# Lenovo thinkpad laptop shutting down on its own

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown, thinkpad, charging

I have a very weird problem with my lenovo thinkpad E540.
Sometimes when I use the laptop it shows a message that the battery is very low and the laptop shuts down on its own. Perhaps i should say sleeps itself. Because when I turn it on again it boots fast and the program data is saved.
The problem occurs roughly every 2-3 hours of use. Now the weird thing is that it occurs ONLY when the laptop is plugged in and charging. It has never occured when I use the laptop on battery only. I have also tried using the laptop, plugged with the battery removed and the problem did not occur.
I should also mention that I see no pattern in the battery level when the pc shuts down. Sometimes it shuts down when it is fully charged.
The laptop is runnig Windows 10.
Could this be a faulty charger, or a battery? Or there might be a problem in the internal power management system in my laptop?
I would be very thankful for any help on this peculiar problem.

Comment: Can you remove the battery from the laptop? Wondering if this happens if you are on AC power, with no battery connected. There is a huge list of potential fixes at Tom's. https://forums.tomsguide.com/faq/how-to-solve-random-shutdown-issues-in-lenovo-laptops.188341/#:~:text=If%20the%20issue%20persists%2C%20disconnect,battery%20or%20AC%20adapter%20power.

Comment: Install Lenovo Vantage, enable the battery toolbar and set the Threshold for low battery to 30% and it will warn you before shutting down. Try doing a battery Reset with this tool. Full discharge and then full charge so it will take several hours.